# What is the sum of the coefficients of $P(Q(X))$?

Tags: polynomials

### Given the polynomials:

$P\left(X\right)=a_0+a_1X+...+a_nX^n$

$Q\left(X\right)=b_0+b_1X+...+b_mX^m$

### Provided that:

$\frac{Q(X)}{X-1}$ has the remainder $0$

**What is the sum of the coefficients of $P(Q(X))$?**

$P(Q(X))=a_0+a_1Q(X)+...a_n(Q(X))^n$

I can see that $b_0+b_1+...+b_m=0$ from $Q(1)=0$ (Remainder Theorem), but that's about it...

Can I have some hints on how should I approach this kind of exercise? Thank you

Comment: I think I got it, is it that $a_0+a_1(b_0+b_1X+...+b_mX^m)+....+a_n(b_0+b_1X+...+b_mX^m)^n=a_0$?

Comment: Correct! The sum of the coefficients of a polynomial is its value at $X=1$, so here $P(Q(1)) = P(0)$

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Since $b_1+b_2+...+b_m=0$ and we want to get the sum of coefficients of $a_0+a_1Q(X)+...+a_nQ(X)^n$, all that must be done is replacing Q(X) with it's actual value.

### So we have:

$a_0+a_1(b_0+b_1X+....+b_mX^m)+...+a_n(b_0+b_1X+...b_mX^m)^n$

### And we want the sum of the coefficients, so we set $X=1$

So $a_0+a_1Q(1)+...+a_nQ(1)^n$, and as mentioned in the body of the question, $Q(1)=0$. So the answer is $a_0$.

Comment: Yes, the coef sum of $\,f(x) = p(q(x))\,$ is $\,f(1) =  p(\color{#c00}{q(1)}) = p(0)\ $ by $\,x\!-\!1\mid q\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{q(1)=0}\ $